# Email styles not works

Tags: magento2.3, email-templates, order-email

My email template:

```
    {{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}
<table>
    <tr class="email-intro">
        <td>
            <p class="greeting">{{trans "%name," name=$order.getBillingAddress().getName()}}</p>
            <p>
                {{trans "Thank you for your order from %store_name." store_name=$store.getFrontendName()}}
                {{trans "Once your package ships we will send an email with a link to track your order."}}
                {{trans 'If you have questions about your order, you can email us at <a href="mailto:%store_email">%store_email</a>' store_email=$store_email |raw}}{{depend store_phone}} {{trans 'or call us at <a href="tel:%store_phone">%store_phone</a>' store_phone=$store_phone |raw}}{{/depend}}.
                {{depend store_hours}}
                    {{trans 'Our hours are <span class="no-link">%store_hours</span>.' store_hours=$store_hours |raw}}
                {{/depend}}
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="email-summary">
        <td>
            <h1>{{trans 'Your Order <span class="no-link">#%increment_id</span>' increment_id=$order.increment_id |raw}}</h1>
            <p>{{trans 'Placed on <span class="no-link">%created_at</span>' created_at=$order.getCreatedAtFormatted(2) |raw}}</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="email-information">
        <td>
            {{depend order.getEmailCustomerNote()}}
            <table class="message-info">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        {{var order.getEmailCustomerNote()|escape|nl2br}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            {{/depend}}
            <table class="order-details">
                <tr>
                    <td class="address-details">
                        <h3>{{trans "Billing Info"}}</h3>
                        <p>{{var formattedBillingAddress|raw}}</p>
                    </td>
                    {{depend order.getIsNotVirtual()}}
                    <td class="address-details">
                        <h3>{{trans "Shipping Info"}}</h3>
                        <p>{{var formattedShippingAddress|raw}}</p>
                    </td>
                    {{/depend}}
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="method-info">
                        <h3>{{trans "Payment Method"}}</h3>
                        {{var payment_html|raw}}
                    </td>
                    {{depend order.getIsNotVirtual()}}
                    <td class="method-info">
                        <h3>{{trans "Shipping Method"}}</h3>
                        <p>{{var order.getShippingDescription()}}</p>
                        {{if shipping_msg}}
                        <p>{{var shipping_msg}}</p>
                        {{/if}}
                    </td>
                    {{/depend}}
                </tr>
            </table>
            {{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

I add next css to template styles section:

```
td{background-color:white;}
table{background-color:white;}
tr th{text-align:left;}
tr td{text-align:left;}
```

And nothing happens.

I tried to insert

```
<style type="text/css">
    {{var template_styles|raw}}
</style>
```

but still no result.

On email, some text added to classes, something like `m_4018269044376677402address-details`

Answer (score 0):

Try include css with

```
{{inlinecss file="Vendor_ModuleName::css/filename.css"}}
```

or

```
<style type="text/css">
    {{css file="Vendor_ModuleName::css/filename.css"}}
</style>
```

Comment: all styles included in Magento_Email/email/header.html, but still no result.

Comment: @AshenOne It works in magento and for me, look for typos.